# Quick Tkinter Formatting Issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a stack of Frames like this:

```
    +--+
    |  |
  +-+--+-+
  |      |
+-+------+-+
|          |
+----------+
```

But I want them like this:

```
        +--+
        |  |
    +---+--+
    |      |
+---+------+
|          |
+----------+
```

What is the best way to do this?

Was using pack and couldn't get them to behave right.  For some reason, using grid didn't display them at all and my program hangs

```
# Main script
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
for task in TaskList:
    GuiTools.TaskBox.TaskBox(root, task)
root.mainloop() # program hangs from this line, to the point of having to use kill to close it



# Taskbox class
class Taskbox(master, task):
    __init__(self)
        self.TaskFrame = Frame(master, borderwidth=3, relief=RAISED)
         . . .
        Putting stuff in frame
         . . .
        self.TaskFrame.pack() # Gives result 1
        #self.TaskFrame.grid(column=1, sticky='ne') # no display, causes hang
```

Comment: if you're attaching widgets to a particular frame or toplevel, either use all `pack` or all `grid`.  Otherwise, `tk` will happily try to figure out suitable positions for your widgets for all eternity.

Comment: @mgilson I think this is probably what is going on. I use pack to shrinkwrap the frame onto one of the components so I can achieve some other functionality I was working on. When I put grid in there, this would cause the hang.

Comment: Probably.  I don't know much about `pack` since I never use it (It's very counter intuitive for me, but some people seem to use it a lot ...).

Comment: Just to be clear: you can use pack and grid in the same application, just not both in the same container widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky to answer without knowing what you're putting into the frames in the first place.  @sc0tt is correct that you probably want to use `sticky=tk.E`, however, that might not be good enough to get what you want since your frames will likely resize themselves depending on what you put in them (unless you do `myframe.grid_propagate(False)`).  The solution to this is to put in the `columnspan` keyword as well.

Here's a stupid loop which will do something like what you want:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
frames = []
for i in range(3):
    f = tk.Frame(root)
    f.grid(row=i, column=0, columnspan=i+1, sticky=tk.E)
    frames.append(f)

#Now, you can add buffer spaces (frames) into the grid at 
# `row=0,column=0`, `row=0,column=1` and `row=1,column=1` if you need it. 

root.mainloop()
```

This effectively partitions your grid like this:

```
+----+-----+-----+
|    |     |     |
+----+-----+-----+
|    |           |
+----+-----------+
|                |
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You almost have it. You're starting your `mainloop` before you add the widgets to your window, which will cause them not to be added until the `mainloop` finishes. When the mainloop finishes, the window is no longer available, so adding them will fail.

Here's a quick example of 3 frames on top of each other like how you wanted:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
frame_one = Tkinter.Frame(root, width="50", height="50", borderwidth=3, relief=Tkinter.RAISED)
frame_one.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E)

frame_two = Tkinter.Frame(root, width="100", height="100", borderwidth=3, relief=Tkinter.RAISED)
frame_two.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E)

frame_three = Tkinter.Frame(root, width="150", height="150", borderwidth=3, relief=Tkinter.RAISED)
frame_three.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't tell the OP to create a frame and then grid it all in one line.  Now you have no (easy) handle on the frames you've created since `.grid` returns `None`.  The only way to actually use the frames you've just created is to somehow pull them out of `root` (probably via `root.children` sorting out the frames explicitly and somehow figuring out which ones you want...).  This is messy at best.

Comment: I totally agree, I was gridding on the same line for the purpose of a short example. I'll edit it now.

Comment: @mgilson.  The OP should be able to pull this apart to suit his needs.  This is just a toy example showing how it can be done.

Comment: @sc0tt All of the adding stuff to the frame works just fine. These are 2 different files, I just ran them together here so they were readable. Tried to indicate that with comments.  I would use the approach suggested except that I have an incoming list of variable length, so I cannot declare each frame individually

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- Typically I agree with that, however this is one point where I've seen people have issues in the past.  If someone who doesn't know `Tkinter` stumbles upon this post, then they'll think tk.Widget().grid()` is the way things are done causing more confusion when things break.  SO answers are not just for the OP, but also for the community as a whole and therefore I think they should be a reference to good practice whenever appropriate.